# How to make changes in Linux file that has permisison to be written only by group

Tags: bash, file, privileges

There is a file 'Open\me' in the home directory of user petro in Linux.
His `ls -l` is the next:
`-----w---- 1 petro petro 0 гру 10 10:19 'Open\me'`
Meaning that all who belongs to the group petro has right to make changes in file 'Open\me'.
I've logged in as another user - vitaliy. I'm included to the group petro `petro:x:1400:vitaliy`.
I've tried `echo hello > 'Open\me'`
But i still can't write in this file. Access is denied.
So is it possible to make changes in file except adding running (x) to group privileges?

Comment: Do you have `rx` permissions to the parent directory?

Comment: I checked. Yes, i have. ```drwxr-xr-x 15 petro    petro    4096 гру 10 11:33 INTERNAL```. Home directory - Internal.

Comment: do you have `selinux` enabled? does `id` shows that you're a member of `petro` group?

Comment: No, ```seLinux``` is disabled. I use Debian. Firstly my ```id``` showed that i'm not a member of ```petro``` group. but when i used ```id vitaliy``` it showed me that i belonged to group petro. Then i used ```id -G``` it assured me i was included to that group. I've just repeated ```echo hello > 'Open\me'``` and it worked!!!